# Polynomial in a non-degenerate interval

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, continuity

'We can't find a non-zero polynomial which is zero on a non-degenerate interval'.

- why ?
- what is a non-degenerate interval ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any polynomial $p(x)$ has a finite number of roots except when $p(x)=0$, and any non-degenerate interval contains uncountably infinite points, hence the polynomial is the zero polynomial.

A non-degenerate interval is an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ with at least $2$ points.

Answer (score 0):

Non degenerate interval just means not a single point. Otherwise known as an "interval".

A nonzero polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots.